# Binding several inherited models to the same route laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I've got 3 models, all of which inherit an abstract `Plan` model, `BehaviourPlan`, `AffirmationPlan` and `ProfilePlan`

Is it possible to have all of them served by the same route? This is what I've got so far, but because `Plan` is abstract it throws `Target [App\Plan] is not instantiable.`

```
Route::prefix('plans')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{plan}', function (\App\Plan $plan) {
        dd($plan);
    });
});
```

Comment: I suspect you'll either have to make `Plan` non-abstract, or use `Model` as the type hint.

Comment: you can point the route to a controller, then instantiate those three models and use them in that controller

Comment: @AmritShrestha I think you're misreading the question. OP want's the `plan` route to take one of *several* possible classes, each of which inherits from the parent `App\Plan`. Kinda like a polymorphic relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by altering the slugs of each plan to be prefixed with their type, and then just running an `if` statement to retrieve the plan within a controller, like:

```
public function show(Student $student, string $plan_id)
    {
        $plan = null;
        if(starts_with($plan_id, "behaviour"))
        {
            $plan = BehaviourPlan::where('slug', $plan_id)->first();
        }
        else if(starts_with($plan_id, "affirmation"))
        {
            $plan = AffirmationPlan::where('slug', $plan_id)->first();
        }
        else if(starts_with($plan_id, "profile"))
        {
            $plan = ProfilePlan::where('slug', $plan_id)->first();
        }

        if ($plan == null)
            return abort('404');

        dd($plan);
    }
```

It seems a bit rough-and-ready though, so I'm still on the lookout for a neater way to fix this issue